# Se puede ejecutar una clase a traves de un Runtime.getRuntime().exec()

Tags: java, proceso

Mi pregunta es un tanto teórica.

-La cuestión principal es si se puede crear un proceso hijo llamando a una clase java para que esta se ejecute y devuelva un valor al proceso padre.

-**Por ejemplo:** `Process p= Runtime.getRuntime().exec(Clase.java);`

Hay alguna manera de que creando un proceso de este tipo se pueda ejecutar otra clase que envie valores a la primera?

Muchas gracias a todos!

Comment: La clase no es ejecutable, es interpretada por el JVM. Puedes lanzar un JVM separado ("java Clase") igual que lanzas cualquier otro programa java. Lo que no queda claro es porqué quieres hacer esto en vez de instanciar la clase en la propia JVM inicial.

Comment: tengo un ejercicio que me pide que un proceso padre y uno hijo se comuniquen bidireccionalmente con streams, pero cada uno que haga sus cosas ( un proceso realiza una acción , cuando este termina realiza otra diferente el proceso hijo) entonces queria saber si se podria hacer eso.

Comment: ¿Te han dicho que lo hagas en Java? No es que no se pueda hacer, pero estas cosas de Sistema Operativo suele hacerse con C o scripts. En todo caso se trata de usar la entrada y la salida estandar del proceso hijo.